# Why ec2 instances get metadata over REST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

EC2 documentation says that it is possible to get instance specific metadata, such as instance-id, ami-id, etc over a REST call to 169.254.169.254 . My question is: since this information is available to the instance at launch time, why doesn't AWS just write it to a file in the /etc dir?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons:

1. Some of the information is dynamic, that being that it changes over time. Using a REST interface allows the software that wants the information to get the current values when they need them.
2. Amazon adds new metadata and new metadata versions from time-to-time. Using a REST interface lets you query the data and version you want without needing to bake the new data schema and version into the OS AMI.
3. The information needs to come from somewhere. Even if it's placed on a file in the OS, it has to get there somehow. A REST interface is simply that conduit.

Answer (score -1):

That data does actually exist in the file system, though its location could vary from one AMI type to another.  Using the RESTful interface gives you a more reliable way at getting at the data.

Comment: Where on the file system does it exist on, say, a stock Amazon Linux instance?

Comment: @JoeTaylor NOt sure on Amazon Linux, but you might try `/var/lib/cloud/data`